# Buggy Text Replace code:

Tags: python, string, replace

I cant seem to figure out why I keep getting this buggy output.

Input file:

```
ff1
ff2
ff3
ff10
ff11
ff20
ff21
ff23
gb20
gb10
gh23
```

Output File:

```
FF01
FF02
FF03
FF010
FF011
FF020
FF021
FF023
GB020
GB010
GH023
```

Code:

```
import os
import sys

#directory is the directory we will work from
directory = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop"
os.chdir(directory)

renameWhat = ["ff", "gb", "gh"]

oldFile = open("New Text Document.txt")
buffer = oldFile.read()

for item in renameWhat:
    for i in range(0, 50):
        if i < 10:
            buffer = buffer.replace(item + str(i), item.upper() + "0" + str(i))
        else:
            buffer = buffer.replace(item + str(i), item.upper() + str(i))

outFile = open("test.txt", "w")
outFile.write(buffer)
outFile.close()
oldFile.close()
```

What needs to happen:

I'm trying to replace ff to uppercase (done), then I need to add zero's to all numbers that are `less than or equal to 9`. So I think that `if i is less than 10` should be good enough; but it's not because it's adding zeroes to everything over 9. I have tried with `len(str(i))` to make sure it's only of length one, but that still does not work; what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your original solution doesn't work is that it isn't checking that it's matching a whole line/word/number. So for instance after replacing `ff1` with `FF01` your buffer is now:

```
FF01
ff2
ff3
FF010
FF011
ff20
ff21
ff23
gb20
gb10
gh23
```

Comment: Cant believe I missed such a rudimentary error; yet not so obvious bug. I just added the file extensions to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution:

```
with open("New Text Document.txt") as oldFile:
    with open("test.txt", "w") as outFile:
        for line in oldFile:
            start, end = line[:2], line[2:]
            outfile.write(start.upper() + end.strip().zfill(2) + '\n')
```

If you only want to uppercase specific prefixes:

```
with open("New Text Document.txt") as oldFile:
    with open("test.txt", "w") as outFile:
        for line in oldFile:
            start, end = line[:2], line[2:]
            if start in renameWhat:
                start = start.upper()
            outfile.write(start + end.strip().zfill(2) + '\n')
```

Comment: don't you mean `line[:2]` etc instead of `buffer`?

Comment: np you just barely beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [zfill string method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill):

```
>>> str(1).zfill(2)
'01'
>>> str(10).zfill(2)
'10'
```

Comment: That's a direct paste from a python prompt.  And I believe you mean prepending.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
a = """ff1
ff2
ff3
ff10
ff11
ff20
ff21
ff23
gb20
gb10
gh23
"""

regex = re.compile('([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]*)\n')
b = ""
for i in regex.findall(a):
    if i[0] in ['ff','gb','gh']:
        b+=i[0].upper()
    else:
        b+=i[0]
    if int(i[1]) < 10:
        b+= "0"
    b+= i[1]+"\n"
print b
```

Result:

```
FF01
FF02
FF03
FF10
FF11
FF20
FF21
FF23
GB20
GB10
GH23
```

Comment: No need for a regex for something this simple -- it's what the built in string methods are for.

Comment: @agf: True. But then again it's simple enough it doesn't really matter